# VMWare vs Azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vmware

I searched the internet but couldnt find an answer. I know that VMWare gives you a true full virtual machine with a assigned NIC card where Azure virtual machine which is connected through Remote Desktop does not do full virtual. Is full virtual the correct terminology used to describe this or am I wrong?

The reason this came up is because I have both environments to play with at work and have multiple customers with different vpn setup. I've noticed that if split tunneling disabled, I cannot use Azure virtual machine and would have to setup on VMWare unless I use something like TeamViewer to connect into the Azure virtual machine.

One of my customer (customer A), blocks all traffic after the VPN is established. This includes RDP and HTTP, the only way for this to work is to install a virtual machine on VMware and use vSphere to connect in.

My last question, is it possible to get this one customer A working on Azure? My management team wants the IT shop to be all Microsoft so that means they dont want to use VMware anymore. I've tried using TeamViewer but after connecting to VPN (Cisco Anyconect) the connection to TeamViewer gets disconnected because it runs on 80 HTTP and 443 HTTPS. Any work around on Azure that anyone would like to share? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure runs on Hyper-V, which is Microsoft virtualization technology. A hyper-V image from on-premises can also be run in Azure (with a few limitations).

I read up quickly on vSphere, and it appears its an underlying fabric for managing a collection of VMWare based resources. To that end, Microsoft does have both remote powershell, as well as System Center for remote management of virtual machines.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks that does help me understand a little but I am facing an issue with the VPN where it works in vSphere and it does not work in Azure. I needed to know why it doesnt work and if possible a work around solution.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is fairly broad. We'd need more details on exactly what isn't working before I can offer up any useful advice. Sorry. :(